# Super slow mysql query - optimization needed

Tags: mysql

I'm not sure if this is a problem of sql server optimization or a query problem, but here goes.

I have a database of articles from various news outlets that I inherited. There are two tables: news_articles and news_outlets. I'm trying to determine the number of distinct articles, allowing for the same article to be published in multiple outlets (there's a lot of duplicates in the database).

Here's my query:

```
SELECT outs.id, outs.site, COUNT(DISTINCT CONCAT(arts.body_text, outs.site)) AS Article_Count, outs.alignment
FROM news_articles arts
INNER JOIN 
news_outlets outs ON arts.outlet_id = outs.id
WHERE
arts.search_perc > 0.0
AND
arts.search_perc < 0.85
AND
outs.out_type < 3
GROUP BY outs.site, outs.alignment
```

Note: Unfortunately, due to the original design of the database (which I don't have time to fix) there are also multiple outlet_ids per actual news outlet (imagine a web crawler returning the same page for mobile.cnn.com and www.cnn.com and you have the issue; each of those has a separate outlet_id). That's not something I can easily fix right now.

There are indexes on outs.site, outs.alignment, both ids, and outs.out_type. All tables are innodb. There are about 800 records in news_outlets and about 6M in news_articles. This is running from a python connection to the server (on the same workstation) using MySQLdb. The workstation is a 2.7GHz i5 from this year with 16GB of ram. I haven't altered my.cnf much, but I did modify this:
    innodb_buffer_pool_size = 12288M

It doesn't seem to make much difference either way.

This query runs for a very long time (though not always - when I was running a very similar query last night it seemed to be much faster). I recognize that it's doing a lot, so it's understandable.  Yet EXPLAIN says there are 2 simple processes: one that uses where, filesort; another that uses an index condition and where.

Whenever I run SHOW processlist it says the query is Creating sort index. Yet the cpu usage peaks at a maximum of 5%.

Is this a server optimization problem? A query optimization problem? How can I fix it? I have about 60 such queries to run - none have completed; I tend to kill them after 10-20 minutes.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: You should add the output of EXPLAIN <your query>. Maybe a combined index could improve the performance of this query.

Comment: I am going to presume the count takes a HUGE amount of processing that cannot be optimised (at least not in MySQL). Do you need this? Do you need to count it in exactly this way? Because you are joining outs by id I don't think outs.site will ever be different for each concat. So at least change this to COUNT(DISTINCT arts.body_text). But this column may still contain a lot of data. I wonder why the body_text of multiple articles will ever be exactly the same. But this is just based on column names. If they will never be the same, or it does not really matter, you can just COUNT(arts.id)

Comment: Well I do need to check both fields. Could I do a combined checksum on them? As for processing - it's just really weird to me that CPU usage is so low.

Comment: I am saying you don't need to check both fields because it will be impossible for outs.site to change within one result row. You're doing a group by on that column.

Comment: Oooh. Good point. I'll try that. Thanks.

Comment: Upsizing [join_buffer_size](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_join_buffer_size) could be a worth a try too.

Comment: That worked @ontrack. But I can't mark yours as the answer! :(

Comment: I'll place an answer containing the comment

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Answer from comments

---

I am going to presume the count takes a HUGE amount of processing that cannot be optimised (at least not in MySQL). Do you need this? Do you need to count it in exactly this way? Because you are joining outs by id I don't think outs.site will ever be different for each concat. So at least change this to COUNT(DISTINCT arts.body_text).

You don't need to check both fields because it will be impossible for outs.site to change within one result row. You're doing a group by on that column.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT  outs.id, 
outs.site, 
COUNT(DISTINCT CONCAT(arts.body_text, outs.site)) AS Article_Count,     outs.alignment FROM     (SELECT *
FROM    news_articles na
WHERE   na.search_perc > 0.0
AND na.search_perc < 0.85)arts INNER JOIN ( SELECT *
    FROM news_outlets no
    WHERE outs.out_type < 3) outs ON    arts.outlet_id = outs.id GROUP BY outs.site, outs.alignment
```

Comment: That will throw a syntax error. It's SELECT ... FROM ... JOIN ... WHERE. This order is fixed.

Comment: i didn't try, but it should work. It is inline table.

Comment: I'm running that now and checking it. So far it doesn't seem to be much different.

Comment: Please create a index to search_perc.

Answer (score 0):

**Try this - another option, I need to write this without know much about your table structure**
`SELECT  outs.id, 
        outs.site, 
        outs.alignment,
        (   SELECT  COUNT ( DISTINCT (arts.body_text)
            FROM    news_articles na
            WHERE   no.outlet_id = na.id 
            AND     na.search_perc > 0.0
            AND     na.search_perc < 0.85) AS Article_Count 
        COUNT(DISTINCT CONCAT(arts.body_text, outs.site)) 
FROM    news_outlets no
WHERE   outs.out_type < 3`